# why the starting mc rotates while bezier tween

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder, gsap

i am using greensock bezier plugin tween. Hey i got another serious issue , now from the following pic you can see that the bezier path is set for the mc

[image: Capture.png]

and when you click tween the mc automatically turns upside down or anything based on the curve , like right now its around 180 degree and for a different curve the starting rotation is different , how can i find the first initial rotation so that i can reduce it and make it play from 0 rotation

[image: Capture2.png]

I hope you understand what i mean , i am trying to run the bezier where the initial rotation doesnt change , i know we can change the autorotate array for bezier but for that i need to know the initial rotation or tell me how can i make my mc not rotate and auto rotate along the same initial rotation along the path ?

Comment: You ticked `autoRotate` option so what do you expect? What's wrong with `autoRotate:false`? If you want the MC upright for some points but rotating for other points in the bezier path, then you will have to chain up different tweens (y'know.. one tween goes from point 0 to point 2 = no autoRotate, then next tween goes from point 2 to final point 3 with autoRotation)..

Comment: The think is it flips vertically based on the curve , we have a option in greensock where i can add rotation to the autorotated mc's. all i need to know is what rotation is it at the beginning of the curve , if you dont know how greensock works i dont think thats a great answer , because what you have said is to move without autorotate from 1 to 2 and then enable autorotate , if i do that then it will flick to some degree at the starting point of 2 , i dont think you know greensock at all , learn it , it will be useful before you can post some comments.

Comment: You're right I don't use GreenSock, I write my own tweening functions using `ENTER_FRAME` event. If I'm lazy I use **Caurina** or **BtweenAS3** since I personally like those. I'm suggesting a logical thing for you try while you wait for an answer, but if it "flicks" then that's illogical to me & I'll leave you to suffer with that system... I've looked at the source code and the clue you need is on this **[AS file](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-AS3/blob/master/src/com/greensock/plugins/BezierPlugin.as)**. Are you even tracking the Object's `.rotation` via enterframe to find the offset?

Comment: yes i tried to watch the `.rotation` still no luck because at first it stays at 0 and moves to some othe rotation and it continues for 3 updates and the on the 4th or 5th update it shows the correct offset so it is not reliable

Comment: According to that **[AS file](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-AS3/blob/master/src/com/greensock/plugins/BezierPlugin.as)** _"...if you want to offset the rotation by a certain amount (in degrees), you can define a number like `autoRotate:90`"_ try that instead of saying `autoRotate:true`. Something like `autoRotate: -180` might work but can't test right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the initial rotation, why not just check it directly on your mc? Like set immediateRender:true on your tween and then check mc.rotation. Or grab a reference to the tween and alter its progress() to whatever you want and check the rotation at that point. Also, you can offset the rotation by any amount you want by setting autoRotate to that number of degrees. It's super flexible.